# Haskell type instance failed to resolve

Tags: haskell, type-families, recursion-schemes

I'm trying to create a `Cofree` structure by anamorphism, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134949/haskell-labeling-an-ast-with-type-information-using-algorithm-w?rq=1). But the compiler complains about type mismatch:

```
Expected type: Base (Cofree Term E) (E, Fix Term)
  Actual type: CofreeF Term E (E, Fix Term)
```

But at the source code of `recursion-schemes` package, there is an type instance definition:

```
type instance Base (Cofree f a) = CofreeF f a
```

How can I make the haskell compiler unify that type with this specific type instance equation successfully?

The code is almost the same as in the link:

```
import qualified Control.Comonad.Trans.Cofree as COFREEF

type E = Int
type Term = Maybe

annotate :: E -> Fix Term -> COFREEF.Cofree Term E
annotate = curry (ana coalg)
  where
    coalg :: (E, Fix Term) -> COFREEF.CofreeF Term E (E, Fix Term)
    coalg (environment, Fix term) = environment COFREEF.:< fmap ((,) 
environment) term
```

And the exact error message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘COFREEF.CofreeF Term E (E, Fix Term)’
                 with ‘Compose
                         Data.Functor.Identity.Identity
                         (COFREEF.CofreeF Maybe Int)
                         (E, Fix Term)’
  Expected type: (E, Fix Term)
                 -> Base (COFREEF.Cofree Term E) (E, Fix Term)
    Actual type: (E, Fix Term)
                 -> COFREEF.CofreeF Term E (E, Fix Term)
• In the first argument of ‘ana’, namely ‘coalg’
  In the first argument of ‘curry’, namely ‘(ana coalg)’
  In the expression: curry (ana coalg)
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question, as well as what version of `recursion-schemes` you're using

Comment: The code is exactly same as the `annotate` function in the link, with `Term` aliased to `Maybe` and `E` aliased to `Int`, and `calcEnv` function is replaced by `const`.

The version of `recursion-schemes` is 5.0.2

Comment: Huh, it looks to me like the first part of the error (mentioning Compose) is not consistent with the "Expected ... Actual... " part, which seems like a bug but  I may be missing something. What ghc version?

Comment: GHC version is 8.2.2

Comment: @jberryman No, GHC is fine. The actual type here corresponds to the very first type in the message, and the expected type the second. That is, the types in the message are ordered "actual expected expected actual."

Comment: Oh the trouble is I read `CofreeF` as `Cofree` so it looked like GHC was giving a nonsensical error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cofree` is just a type synonym

```
newtype CofreeT f w a = CofreeT { runCofreeT :: w (CofreeF f a (CofreeT f w a)) }
type Cofree f = CofreeT f Identity
```

and it is `CofreeT` that has a `Base` instance:

```
type instance Base (CofreeT f w a) = Compose w (CofreeF f a)
-- Base (Cofree f a) ~ Base (CofreeT f Identity a) ~ Compose Identity (CofreeF f a)
```

The equation from the question is morally equivalent, but it's not a good enough approximation.

Wrap your coalgebra in `Compose . Identity`

```
annotate :: E -> Fix Term -> Cofree Term E
annotate = curry $ ana $ Compose . Identity . coalg
  where
    coalg :: (E, Fix Term) -> CofreeF Term E (E, Fix Term)
    coalg (environment, Fix term) = environment :< fmap (environment,) term
```

Comment: Finally I found out that I should import `CofreeF(..)` from `Control.Comonad.Trans.Cofree` and `Cofree` from `Control.Comonad.Cofree` for `recursion-schemes`... It's a bit wired.